# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, filter, async-await, promise, array-map

I am working on a project using the Poke API.

My problem is when trying to filter the data from a search input,
I get the error: *Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')*

When someone types in the search bar, I'm using filter to return a new array that matches either a name, id number, or type.  I can see that a new array is returned, but the program breaks when trying to display the filtered data on the page.

It looks like the error occurs because the filter cannot iterate over a promise used to map specific data from the original array.  But I'm not sure how to move forward.

I'm grateful to anyone who can point me in the right direction.  Thanks for your help.

**JS**

```
const searchBar = document.getElementById('searchBar');
const pokemonData = [];

  const getPokemonData = async () => {
    
        for (let i = 1; i <= 151; i++) {
            const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${i}`;
            const res = await fetch(url);
            const data = await res.json();
            
            pokemonData.push(data);
        }
    
        Promise.all(pokemonData).then( (results) => {
    
            const pokemon = results.map( (data) => ({
                name: data.name,
                id: data.id,
                image: data.sprites['front_shiny'],
                type: data.types.map((type) => type.type.name)
            }));
    
            //console.log(pokemon);
            displayPokemon(pokemon);
    
        });
}


const displayPokemon = (pokemon) => {

    //console.log(pokemon);

    const pokeDexContainer = document.querySelector('.pokedex');

    const generateHtml = (pokemon).map( (mon) => {
        return `
        <li class="poke-card">

            <image class="poke-image" src="${mon.image}" alt="${mon.name}"/>

            ${  
                ( ids => {

                    if (ids < 10) {
                        return `<h2 class="poke-id">00${ids}</h2>`
                    }
                    if (ids >= 10 && ids < 100) {
                        return `<h2 class="poke-id">0${ids}</h2>`
                    }
                    if (ids >= 100) {
                        return `<h2 class="poke-id">${ids}</h2>`
                    }

                })(mon.id)
            }

            <h1 class="poke-name">${mon.name}</h1>

            //error message points here
           //Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
            ${mon.type.map( (types) => { 
                 return `<span class="poke-type ${types}">${types}</span>`

            } ).join('')}

        </li>
        `
    }).join('');

    pokeDexContainer.innerHTML = generateHtml;

}

getPokemonData();


searchBar.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
        //console.log(event.target.value);
    
        const searchString = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
        const searchNumber = event.target.value;
    
        const filteredPokemon = pokemonData.filter( (mon) => {
            return (
                mon.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchString) ||
                mon.id == searchNumber ||
                mon.type == searchString
            );
        });
    
        console.log(filteredPokemon);
    
        displayPokemon(filteredPokemon);
    
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- search bar -->

<div id="search">
     <input type="text" name="searchBar" id="searchBar" placeholder="search pokedex"/>
</div>

<!-- pokemon list container -->

<ul class="pokedex"></ul>
```

Comment: There are 4 instances of `.map()` in your code, which one triggers the error?

Comment: `Promise.all(pokemonData).then(` is pointless. `pokemonData` is an array holding the actual data already, not promises.

Comment: @Phil in the generateHtml function.  There's a .map() that iterates over the poke types and returns a span element

'${mon.type.map( (types) => { 
                 return `<span class="poke-type ${types}">${types}</span>`

            } ).join('')}'

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, in case this may be helpful to someone else.

The displayPokemon function would break when passing in filteredPokemon.  filteredPokemon was iterating over the pokemonData array which holds the raw data from the Poke API.

Instead filteredPokemon needs to iterate over the pokemon map within the getPokemonData function, which is how displayPokemon displays the correct data.

So, we push the pokemon map to a new array using the spread operator and iterate over new array in filteredPokemon.

```
let pokemonResults = [];

  const getPokemonData = async () => {

  let pokemonData = [];
    
        for (let i = 1; i <= 151; i++) {
            const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${i}`;
            const res = await fetch(url);
            const data = await res.json();
            
            pokemonData.push(data);
        }
    
        Promise.all(pokemonData).then( (results) => {
    
            const pokemon = results.map( (data) => ({
                name: data.name,
                id: data.id,
                image: data.sprites['front_shiny'],
                type: data.types.map((type) => type.type.name)
            }));
    
            pokemonResults.push(...pokemon);
            displayPokemon(pokemon);
    
        });
}
```

Note: Since pokemon types returns an array, it needs to be converted to a string in order to get the correct search results.

```
searchBar.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
    
        const searchString = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
        const searchNumber = event.target.value;
    
        const filteredPokemon = pokemonResults.filter( (mon) => {
            return (
                mon.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchString) ||
                mon.id == searchNumber ||
                JSON.stringify(mon.type).toLowerCase().includes(searchString)
            );
        });
    
        displayPokemon(filteredPokemon);
    
    });
```